# Conditional groupingBy: advanced Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I have a task that I would like to do with just streams, in essence its a complicated grouping by operation on a list of objects. Lets pretend like the below table is a list of objects (the columns are the members of the objects).

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| obj 1 | j | k | k | l | m | o | q | 6 | t |
| obj 2 | j | k | k | l | m | o | q | 8 | t |
| obj 3 | j | k | k | l | m | o | u | 8 | t |
| obj 4 | a | a | a | a | m | a | a | a | t |

I first need to group by A, B, C, D, I. Easy.

```
data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A + B + C + D + I)
```

group1

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| obj 1 | j | k | k | l | m | o | q | 6 | t |
| obj 2 | j | k | k | l | m | o | q | 8 | t |
| obj 3 | j | k | k | l | m | o | u | 8 | t |

group 2

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| obj 4 | a | a | a | a | m | a | a | a | t |

Then if the resulting map has groups where the column `E` has duplicate values i.e. group 1 (duplicate value m in obj 1, 2,3). I need to look at column `F` and `G`. For all rows where `F` has all the same values AND `G` as all the same values then I need to add up the values in Column H, and combine the rows. If the values are different I need to leave them as they are and create a new group. I cant just group by column F because If there are no duplicate elements in the group, I want them to stay in the same group. if column `m` had all different values, no 'secondary' grouping would occur. The result of the above tables would be

group1

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| obj 1 | j | k | k | l | m | o | q | 14 | t |

group 2

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| obj 3 | j | k | k | l | m | o | u | 8 | t |

group 3

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| obj 4 | a | a | a | a | m | a | q | a | t |

part of me thinks this isnt possible with streams and I should just cut my losses but also not very well versed in java streams. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show the code you’ve written without streams. That will de-obfuscate your requirements and prove the correctness of a stream-based implementation. Also, keep in mind, streams are merely one tool for readability—a virtue that is quickly lost in all but their simplest applications.

Comment: E.g. Field H is summed but you don’t specify a reduction for field I.

Comment: @erickson its used in the initial group by

Comment: Gotcha. Why not group by ABCDEFGI, merging duplicates by summing H?

Comment: Have you considered a simple nested loop or perhaps a loop/stream hybrid solution?  Imo, the time it takes to figure this out has diminishing returns and the result would probably not be a efficient as a more simple construct.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you should be able to [group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) items by ABCDEFGI, then [combine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) any items with duplicate keys by summing H. There doesn't appear to be a need for multiple grouping operations.

Because you failed to provide any code, I had to make up an example. I tried to follow the rough description you gave while reducing the repetition that would be required for so many fields. The information provided makes me suspect that combining those eight different key fields into an additional object might improve your API, and allow you to incorporate some of the helper code into your class.

```java
final class Key {

    static Collection<? extends YourClass> consolidate(Collection<? extends YourClass> items) {
        return items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Key::new, Collectors.reducing(null, Key::merge)))
            .values();
    }

    private final YourClass val;

    /**
     * @param val an instance of your class to be wrapped for testing equality of key fields
     */
    private Key(YourClass val) {this.val = val;}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Key)) return false;
        YourClass that = ((Key) obj).val;
        return Objects.equals(val.a, that.a) && Objects.equals(val.b, that.b);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(val.a, val.b);
    }

    /**
     * @param o1 an instance of your class
     * @param o2 another instance of your class
     * @return an instance that representing the combination of {@code o1} and {@code o2}
     */
    private static YourClass merge(YourClass o1, YourClass o2) {
        if (o1 == null) return o2;
        if (o2 == null) return o1;
        if (!Objects.equals(o1.a, o2.a)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        if (!Objects.equals(o1.b, o2.b)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return new YourClass(o1.a, o1.b, o1.h + o2.h);
    }

}

final class YourClass {
    final String a, b;
    final int h;
    YourClass(String a, String b, int h) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.h = h;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return a + ' ' + b + ": " + h;
    }
}
```